Add-in for Outlook using visual basic to move an email to a different folder
This code saves the email to the hard drive.
I want to move the email to a different folder.
Public Sub SaveMail()
    ' Variables for accessing selected mail item
    Dim myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer
    Dim myOlApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim myOlSel As Outlook.Selection
    Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim sName As String

    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder

    'Dim fileName As String

    myOlExp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer()
    myOlSel = myOlExp.Selection

    If myOlSel.Item(1).Class <> Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlObjectClass.olMail Then             'If selected item is not a mail item
        MsgBox("Please select a mail item")
    Else 'Else save mail item to location
        oMail = myOlSel.Item(1)
        sName = oMail.Subject
        sName = ReplaceCharsForFileName(sName, "")

        'Save to folder on harddrive
        fileName.fileName = "\\Folder\" & sName & ".msg"
        oMail.SaveAs(fileName.fileName, Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG)

        'Move to different folder in outlook (not working)
        myNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
        myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders("Outlookfolder")
        oMail.Move(myDestFolder)

    End If
End Sub

It saves to the hard drive but does not move to a different folder.

Are you sure myDestFolder is not null? Do you have "On Error Resume Next" anywhere in your code?
